# C++: Is it correct to create a dump using task manager while debugging in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, dump, taskmanager

I set a breakpoint in C++ my code and caught it while my program was running.
Then I created a dump file using Task Manager (not Visual Studio itself).
I opened the result dump but didn't find the code where I set the breakpoint. Although I was viewing the same thread where my breakpoint was set, there was completely different stack trace.
What's the reason why this could happen? Am I allowed to create dump by other applications (for example, Task Manager) while debugging in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

An entire book is needed to explain possible reasons. It could be related to [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization).

Read at least a [good operating system textbook](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/).

Then read a good compiler textbook, like [the Dragon book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools).

Windows and Visual Studio are proprietary applications. If you installed Linux and GCC on your laptop (since the Linux [kernel](https://kernel.org/) and the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler and the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger and [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) are free software) you could take months to dive into their source code and understand their behavior. On Linux, you could use [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to understand [syscall(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), and [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) and [pmap(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pmap.1.html) to understand the address space of processes.

If you have to use Windows, take several weeks to read the  documentation of the [WinAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API). You could guess what Microsoft programmers did.

If you are allowed to use Linux, read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) then study the source code of open source applications (e.g. compilers) interesting to you.